# Is it required to lock shared variables in perl for read access?

Tags: multithreading, perl, locking

I am using shared variables on perl with use [threads::shared](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html).
That variables can we modified only from single thread, all other threads are only 'reading' that variables.

Is it required in the 'reading' threads to lock

```
  {
    lock $shared_var;
    if ($shared_var > 0) .... ;
  }
```

?

isn't it safe to simple verification without locking (in the 'reading' thread!), like

```
  if ($shared_var > 0) ....
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locking is not required to maintain internal integrity when setting or fetching a scalar.

Whether it's needed or not in your particular case depends on the needs of the reader, the other readers and the writers. It rarely makes sense not to lock, but you haven't provided enough details for us to determine what your needs are.

For example, it might not be acceptable to use an old value after the writer has updated the shared variable. For starters, this can lead to a situation where one thread is still using the old value while the another thread is using the new value, a situation that can be undesirable if those two threads interact.

Comment: 'writer' thread is reading config from database every 5 minutes, and writing that config into shared hash %config; all other (reading) threads, are only accessing that values, like sleep($config{'sleep-time'});

Comment: That doesn't really tell us if the readers are ok with the value changing while they are using it. For example, is ok if one thread is using an old value and another thread is using a new value? That's rarely acceptable. But if it is here, you might not need any locking.

Comment: 'reading' threads are not modifying shared variables (values from hash %config). They are only 'getting' values from it.

Comment: I know. I never said anything that implied they did?! (Note: I added to my earlier comment when you were typing yours.)

Comment: i worry, if in same moment, element of shared hash had one value, like
$config{'sleep_time'} is 1. On the moment, when 'writer' thread was rewriting that value to '2' from '1' - i am afraid, will i get that moment in reader threads old or new values 1 or 2? this is normal. I am afraid to get the garbage in reader thread in the moment, when 'writer' thread is writing, if i'm not using locks.

Comment: You won't get garbage. Locking is not required to maintain internal integrity in sets and fetches.

Comment: I understood. it doesn't matter for me, do i use old value, or updated value in current loop iteration. So if i don't get the 'garabe' while reading variable in the moment or it rewriting by another thread, but i get old value, or new value - this is acceptable for me

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether it's meaningful to test the condition just at some point in time or other. The problem however is that in a vast majority of cases, that Boolean test means other things, which might have already changed by the time you're done reading the condition that says it represents a previous state.

Think about it. If it's an insignificant test, then it means little--and you have to question why you are making it. If it's a significant test, then it is telltale of a coherent state that may or may not exist anymore--you won't know for sure, unless you `lock` it.

A lot of times, say in real-time reporting, you don't really care which snapshot the database hands you, you just want a relatively current one. But, as part of its transaction logic, it keeps a complete picture of how things are prior to a commit. I don't think you're likely to find this in code, where the current state is the current state--and even a state of being in a provisional state is a definite state.

I guess one of the times this can be different is a cyclical access of a queue. If one consumer doesn't get the head record this time around, then one of them will the next time around. You can probably save some processing time, asynchronously accessing the queue counter. But here's a case where it means little *in context* of just one iteration.

In the case above, you would just want to put some locked-level instructions afterward that expected that the queue might actually be empty even if your test suggested it had data. So, if it is just a preliminary test, you would have to have logic that treated the test as unreliable as it actually is.